# Jquery change text ajax request problem

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dynamic-data

I have an html file as coded below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <style>
        .style1 {
            background-color: #c3d9ff;
            font-family:arial,sans-serif;
        }
        .style2 {
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .style3 {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            font-family:arial,sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .style4 {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            font-family:arial,sans-serif;
            text-align: left;
        }
        body {
        font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:15px;
        background-color: ;
        }
        .action_button {
        font-weight:bold;
        float:right;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">$(function() {
    $('.action_button').click(function() {
        var $button = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'action.php',
            data: 'id='+ $(this).attr('id'),
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                var $row = $button.closest('tr');
                var $col = $row.find('.clickme2');
                $row.fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    if (result == 'ACTIVATED') {
                        $button.text('Activate');
                        $col.text('Active');
                    } else if (result == 'INACTIVATED') {
                        $button.text('Inactivate');
                        $col.text('Inactive');
                    }
                }).fadeIn();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <table style="width: 90%" align="center" class="style1">
        <tr>
                <td colspan="7" class="style2">MANAGER</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
          <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">Col1</td>
          <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">Col2</td>
          <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">Col3</td>
          <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">Col4</td>
          <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">Col5</td>
          <td class="style3" style="width: 200px">Col6</td>
          <td class="style3" style="">Action</td>
         </tr>
        </table>
        <td id="main" class="main">
         <td class="update">
        <table style="width: 90%" align="center" class="style1">
            <tr>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataA1</td>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataA2</td>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataA3</td>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataA4</td>
                <td class="style4 clickme2" style="width: 139px">Inactive</td>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 200px">DataA6</td>
           <td>
                    <button href="#" id="DataA1" class="action_button" style="width:80px;height:">
                    Activate</button>
                    </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataB1</td>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataB2</td>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataB3</td>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataB4</td>
                <td class="style4 clickme2" style="width: 139px">Inactive</td>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 200px">DataB6</td>
           <td>
                    <button href="#" id="DataB1" class="action_button" style="width:80px;height:">
                    Activate</button>
                    </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataC1</td>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataC2</td>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataC3</td>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataC4</td>
                <td class="style4 clickme2" style="width: 139px">Active</td>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 200px">DataC6</td>
           <td>
                    <button href="#" id="DataC1" class="action_button" style="width:80px;height:">
                    Inactivate</button>
                    </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataD1</td>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataD2</td>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataD3</td>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataD4</td>
                <td class="style4 clickme2" style="width: 139px">Active</td>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 200px">DataD6</td>
           <td>
                    <button href="#" id="DataD1" class="action_button" style="width:80px;height:">
                    Inactivate</button>
                    </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataE1</td>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataE2</td>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataE3</td>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 139px">DataE4</td>
                <td class="style4 clickme2" style="width: 139px">Inactive</td>
          <td class="style4" style="width: 200px">DataE6</td>
           <td>
                    <button href="#" id="DataE1" class="action_button" style="width:80px;height:">
                    Activate</button>
                    </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
        </td>
        </body>
        </html>
```

The fage contain a table with 5 rows with a button at the end of the row. On click, the button submits data to a php file and then changes text and blurs according to the response from php file. The blur function and change text function in col5 is working well. But the change text function in button got really buggy. The button text should change accordingly. the text of button "Activate" should change to "Inactivate" and the text of button "Inactivate" should change to "Activate" on click / successful submission.. This is not working..

Below is the php file code

```
<?php
$id = $_POST[id];
if($id=="DataA1"){
  echo "ACTIVATED";
}
if($id=="DataB1"){
  echo "ACTIVATED";
}
if($id=="DataE1"){
  echo "ACTIVATED";
}
if($id=="DataC1"){
  echo "INACTIVATED";
}
if($id=="DataD1"){
  echo "INACTIVATED";
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.. :)

blasteralfred

Comment: "got really buggy" isn't much of a problem description.

Comment: Do you need to use the php? I mean, it's easier without it

Comment: yea Christy, i must use php.. it has a lot to do my dear.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution..

Thank you @Heikki, @Cristy..... :)

I corrected the script as below

```
$(function() {
    $('.action_button').click(function() {
        var $button = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'action.php',
            data: 'id='+ $(this).attr('id'),
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                var $row = $button.closest('tr');
                var $col = $row.find('.clickme2');
                $row.fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    if (result == 'ACTIVATED') {
                        $button.text('Inactivate');
                        $col.text('Active');
                    } else if (result == 'INACTIVATED') {
                        $button.text('Activate');
                        $col.text('Inactive');
                    }
                }).fadeIn();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Thanks again ... :)

Comment: You should make some changes to the PHP too, you need to pass "$(this).val()" instead the ID. In the PHP you must check if the val is ACTIVATE then return ACTIVATED, if the val is INACTIVATE return INACTIVATED

Comment: thanks cristy... actually its there in the original php script. in original php, it checks whether value is activated or not, and it process data, make changes and returns corresponding data.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your logic is wrong.  When the button initially says "Activate", you are returning "ACTIVATED" so your button should then read "Inactivate."  You are, however, setting the text to "Activate" again.  Look at the button with id "DataA1" for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$_POST[id]` to `$_POST["id"]`.

Comment: Hi @Heikki, that doesnt solve my problem.. :) .. the text of button "Activate" should change to "Inactivate" and the text of button "Inactivate" should change to "Activate" on click / successfull submission.. this part is not working dude....

Comment: @blasteralfred: It works if the php code echoes the right option. Right now you have hard coded the values so for each element you return the same value on each request.

Comment: Hi @Heikki, everything else other than change text of button is working well dude.. only the button is buggy..

Answer (score 0):

I know you've already solved the problem, but here's my answear anyway:

Replace

```
data: 'id='+ $(this).attr('id'),
```

with

```
data: 'val='+ $button.html(),
```

And, the php file with this:

```
<?php
$val = $_POST['val'];
if(strstr($val,"Activate"))
  echo "ACTIVATED";
else 
  echo "INACTIVATED";
?>
```